# Async testing if a remote method has been called

Tags: groovy, spring-integration, spock

I am trying to use blocking variables for my async testing, following this question

[Verify Spock mock with specified timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666874/verify-spock-mock-with-specified-timeout)

I just want to know that an end method has been called. I tried copying the accepted answer but  the blocking variable was never set.

The blocking variable simply times out.

So I have

```
@TestConfiguration
    static class ITRouterConfiguration {

        private DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

        @Bean
        IVoucherService voucherService() {
            return factory.Mock(IVoucherService)
        }

    }

@Autowired
    private IVoucherService voucherService

 def 'Should create a voucher'() {

        MockQueue mockQueue = mockDestinationManager.createQueue("SERVICE_REQUEST")
        Assert.assertNotNull(jmsTemplate);
        Assert.assertNotNull(mockDestinationManager);

        given:
        def result = new BlockingVariable<Boolean>(0.2) // 200ms
        voucherService.createVoucher() >> {
            result.set(true)
        }
        when: 'a message is sent'
        jmsTemplate.send(mockQueue, new MessageCreator() {


            @Override
            Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(BODY)
                message.setStringProperty(ACTION_TYPE, CREATE)
                return message
            }
        })
        //sleep(2000)

        then: 'check create voucher was called once'
        result.get()
    }

BlockingVariable.get() timed out after 10.00 seconds

    at spock.util.concurrent.BlockingVariable.get(BlockingVariable.java:113)
    at uk.co.cpp.servicerequestrouter.CreateVoucherSpec.Should create a voucher(CreateVoucherSpec.groovy:81)
```

If I leave the sleep in and simple assert

```
1 * voucherService.createVoucher(_)
```

it works, but I don't want to.

Comment: And why `result.get() == WorkResult.OK` doesn't work for you in the `then`: http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/util/concurrent/BlockingVariable.html ?

Comment: BTW, doesn't look like there is something to do with Spring Integration in this question: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration ...

Comment: @ArtemBilan there is a lot to do with it, if you notice the jmsQueues and messages. Last question I called it spring and got told it was spring integration.

Comment: @ArtemBilan  because that was not specified in the accepted answer, so I didn't try it

Comment: I think `200ms` is too little to wait for the service to be called over JMS...

Comment: I ended up waiting 10 seconds but it made no difference. I can find no trace of WorkResult I think that is the value that is being put into the blocking variable (so user configured), but I am just putting a boolean true into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

```
    given:
    def latch = new CountDownLatch(1)

    when: 'a message is sent'
    jmsTemplate.send(mockQueue, new MessageCreator() {

        @Override
        Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(BODY)
            message.setStringProperty(ACTION_TYPE, CREATE)
            return message
        }
    })
    latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // must be in when-block, use timeout variant

    then: 'check create voucher was called once'
    1 * voucherService.createVoucher(_)  >> {
        latch.countDown()
    }
```

Comment: thanks this works but can i ask for more help in asking why (I have added annotations to your post to aid discussion)

Comment: so (1) says wait here until the countdown reaches 0 or 10 seconds elapse. (2) is this adding a body to the method? (3) reduces the countdown by 1, so down to 0 as we only have 1.

Comment: Sorry I can't see your edits. I'll try to guess 1) `latch.await`: yes. 3) `latch.countDown()` yes. As to 2) I don't know what you are referring to.

Comment: my edit was rejected 1 was:  latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  and 2 was  1 * voucherService.createVoucher(_)  >> (more of a basic groovy question)

Comment: `1 * voucherService.createVoucher(_)  >> {` is the mock assertion together with the response, or here the count down. Works even if the method is void.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I encountered this issue too, it is because the voucherService is not a mock object, so the stubbing will not work, you should annotate it with @SpringSpy

Comment: Unfortunatly I no longer have access to any of this code so can't test it and see if it works