Verify @KafkaListener has been called after Kafka producer send in Spock
I have a Spring consumer with @KafkaListener:
@Service
@Slf4j
public class EventListener {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic", groupId = "group-id")
    public void consumer(TheEvent event) {
        log.info("Received the event in {}", event.toString());
    }
}

For testing we are using SpockFramework, and I want to verify the consumer received the published message. In Spock documentation I found PollingConditions however, it seems it's not working with spy method call verifier.
@EmbeddedKafka
class KafkaSpec extend Specification {
    @Autowired
    Producer<String, TheEvent> theEventProducer
    
    @SpringSpy
    EventListener eventListener

    def "produce and consume event successfully"() {
        given: "An event"
        var event = MockEventFactory.createEvent()

        when: "A producer sends the event"
        this.theEventProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, TheEvent>("topic", "123", event))

        then: "Consumer reads event eventually"
        new PollingConditions(timeout: 10).eventually {
            1 * eventListener.consumer(event)
        }
    }
}

The problem is that the PollingCondition after the first condition checking iteration will fail with the below error, and will not wait for the consumer, or try again to check the condition!
Too few invocations for:

1 * eventListener.consumer(event)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):


Waiting to receive the event is the key point for me before start testing the state of the system and the functionality of the code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666874/verify-spock-mock-with-specified-timeout

You can't perform mock assertions in a PollingConditions block. You need to use a CountDownLatch or something similar. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935749/2145769
    def "produce and consume event successfully"() {
        given: "An event"
        var event = MockEventFactory.createEvent()
        var latch = new CountDownLatch(1)

        when: "A producer sends the event"
        this.theEventProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, TheEvent>("topic", "123", event))

        and:
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // must be in when-block, use timeout variant

        then: "Consumer reads event eventually"
        1 * eventListener.consumer(event) >> {
            latch.countDown()
        }        
    }

